# Can't get Gtk.ListBox() object to add new Gtk.ListBoxRow() objects during runtime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I am using Gtk 3.18 on Windows 10 through Python 3.4. I wrote the following script to press a button to add a new Gtk.ListBoxRow() to the self.listbox in my MyWindow class. It happens in the function add_item(self, whatevs).

I clearly mention there

```
self.listbox.add(row)
```

Then why doesn't it work still? The function is being invoked when I press the "Add Item" button. But the list does not get another row. Why so any idea?

Nothing happens. Not even any error is displayed. Can someone please tell me what it is I am doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Win win win")
        self.set_border_width(3)
        self.set_default_size(300, 250)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing = 6)
        self.add(box)

        self.listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
        self.listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.SINGLE)

        box.pack_start(self.listbox, True, True, 0)

        row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box()
        row.add(hbox)
        hbox.pack_start(Gtk.Label("Here is an Item"), True, True, 0)
        self.listbox.add(row)

        hbox = Gtk.Box()

        button_add_item = Gtk.Button(label = "Add Item", valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        button_add_item.connect("clicked", self.add_item)
        hbox.pack_start(button_add_item, True, True, 0)

        button_remove_item = Gtk.Button(label = "Remove Item", valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        button_remove_item.connect("clicked", self.remove_item)
        hbox.pack_start(button_remove_item, True, True, 0)

        box.pack_start(hbox, False, True, 0)

    def add_item(self, whatevs):
        row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box()
        row.add(hbox)
        item_label = Gtk.Label("Here is another Item")
        hbox.pack_start(item_label, True, True,0)
        self.listbox.add(row)

    def remove_item(self, whatevs):
        self.listbox.remove(self.listbox.remove.get_row_at_y(-1))

win = MyWindow()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

By the way can someone tell me why it is that I have to include that other parameter, the one other than "self" in the "connected" functions to the buttons? Any idea how I could use them?

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was wrong. I was supposed to use the Gtk.ListBox.show_all() function of the self.listbox object in my program. Hop this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!

Answer (score 1):

As @shaan-repswal already said, you can call `Gtk.ListBox.show_all()` after adding the widget(s) to the list.

Remember although that if your row contains widgets that you want to keep not visible, you have to, depending on how you manage the widget:

- call [`your_widget.set_no_show_all(True)`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html%23Gtk.Widget.set_no_show_all);
- set the attribute `props.no_show_all` of the widget to `True`.
- add the line

  `<property name="no_show_all">True</property>`

  to the `object` tag of your widget in the glade file.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130873/9402438

Answer (score 0):

I was originally looking for this problem, regarding C. However I stumbled across this question, so the respective function in C is called:

```
gtk_widget_show_all(your_list_box);
```